# Django internal requests

Tags: django

I have project in Django with already written pages. I want to rewrite some of them and put html content using Ajax in Modal window from Twitter Bootstrap. These pages should be internal(access from browser should be forbidden). Is it possible in Django?

Answer (score -1):

You can check `request.is_ajax()` in the view and send back a different template.  I usually do this with passing in a different context variable for the base template that doesn't show any of the usual header, footer, etc. content.